# Javascript - Defining a local variable after assigning a new value in a already declared global variable is overriding the global variable. Why?

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css, reactjs

I am learning javascript global variable and local variable. When I did experiment with it (see jsfiddle below) then I am confuse that why after executing myFunction1() the value of variable a became 4 instead of 5. What do you think happened inside the javascript memory which made its value 4 instead of 5 ?

```js
var a = 4;

myFunction1();
function myFunction1() {
  a= 5;
  var a= 6; 
} 
alert(a); //a = 4


myFunction2();
function myFunction2() {
  a= 5;
} 
alert(a); //a = 5
```

Comment: See duplicate reference. Simply put: a `var` in a function body makes that variable a *local* variable in the *whole* function body, so any use of that variable in that body -- even when occurring before the `var` statement -- concerns that local variable.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You've just discovered [**hoisting**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/Hoisting).

By declaring `var a` inside the function, it is available to the whole function context (even before its declaration), so when you write `a = 5` the actual `a` is not the one you expect, it's the function-scoped `a`.

In the second case, `a` is the one you expect (outside the function)

Comment: Thank you so much @GuerricP . I got it now :)